# Problems with avast after install OSX 10.9.2 update (13C64)

Tags: macos, software-update

The recommendation install OSX 10.9.2 (13C64) took hours to download, and then knocked out my AVAST saying after the upload Avast is incompatible.  It also has caused an non responding pop up box to stay on screen every time I try to open OpenOffie.org... haven't tried anything else yet, and now I see Thunderbolt bridge appearing on my network - hadn't seen it before. It is inactive and I don't know what I am meant to do with it.

What steps can I take to fix the issues with a compatible AVAST?

Comment: Seeing a Thunderbolt bridge in the network settings on a Mac with Thunderbolt is a normal behaviour.

Comment: The thunderbolt bridge lets you have networking over the thunderbolt port work whether or not you also have the thunderbolt to gigabit Ethernet adapter. It used (10.9.x) to get built only when you configure networking on the port. Probably not causing any of the reported issues.

Comment: I had similar problem with Vodafone Mobile app, and Mavericks put it in non compatible software folder. It seems that Mavericks scan during install for compatibility has some issues. What I did, is downloaded (exactly the same version) from Vodafone and Installed it. Now it works.